# good solution to store a specific list of values?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I use following code to retrive the upload order of files. The files must be uploaded in this specific order and cannot be uploaded simultaneously. Therefor I cannot put my code in this for-loop because it would hang the thread.

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [agenciescontroller.arrangedObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

for (NSManagedObject *a in sortedArray)
{
    for (NSMutableDictionary *d in imagescontroller.arrangedObjects)
    {
        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[d valueForKey:[a valueForKey:@"agency"]]] isEqualToString: @"1"])
        {

            ///////////////////////////UPLOAD FILES HERE/////////////////////////////
            checkedchecks += 1;
            NSLog(@"Uploading %@ to %@", [d valueForKey:@"filename"], [a valueForKey:@"agency"]);
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to use this for loop to populate a `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionaries` holding the precise list of files to upload and then go trough this list one by one. Is this a wise idea or is there a better solution? Also keep in mind that once the file is uploaded, I have to update a value inside the mutable dictionary in the foor loop. Where I check for a value = "1" that specific value has to be set to 0 once the upload is finished.

Comment: i'm also a beginner, but i would go for the same solution if this is the only way you can retrive the correct order. but lets wait for some experts.. :)

Comment: You use a lot of variables of which I don't know the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `NSOperationQueue` where you set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property to 1. Then add one `NSOperation` per upload in your existing loop.

To update the value in your dictionary you can add a completion block to your `NSOperation` objects. Just make sure to use the necessary synchronization when updating the value since the completion block will run on some background thread.

Comment: thank you! and how could i edit the value from `1` to `0`? (from this line: `if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[d valueForKey:[a valueForKey:@"agency"]]] isEqualToString: @"1"])
`) by using the array with the dictionary i'd have the informations i need to set that value to 0, but what about the NSOperationQueue?